# Linking to online help for my web app

Tags: electron

I am using Electron for my web app but I want to create online documentation for the app rather than embedding the documentation within the app. The issue I have to deal with is the app's version number. As I release minor or major upgrades to the app, the documentation needs to reflect those changes. However, the person who is using app version 2.0 would see documentation that contains all the 1.0 stuff plus anything new that has been added in 2.0.

There are a number of ways of dealing with this. I could just have a link in the app to a url where each url is specific to a version. The downside to this is that I have to copy all the documentation from the 1.0 page to the 2.0 page and maintaining that could be a hassle.

Another approach is to just use one url but pass the version number in a query string and then hide/show those parts of the documentation that are relevant to their version.

If you've had to deal with this issue, what approach have you taken?

Comment: For me I just have one page of documentation and every time I release a new version then my app silently auto updates for everyone so they're all generally on the latest version and for those that are not I gave them a chance to auto update so it's kinda their fault.